# Program won't continue after initializing input/output streams?

Tags: java, sockets, data-structures, stream

Before people suspect that I have no idea what I'm doing at all (and end up voting this down for no reason at all), please read this:

It connects to my server just fine! I'm getting no errors (from the client OR server), and my server is recognizing the connection. It works with my friend's client that he made, but I wanted to make my own client, and apparently I'm doing something wrong. PLEASE STAY ON TOPIC! Thanks :)

---

Title basically says it all. I've tested with `println` messages above and below the `setupStream()` in my Client.java `run()`, but only the message above the `setupStream()` prints. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to initialize my stream without making my program come to a halt.

Client.java

```
import java.io.IOException;


public class Client extends Stream implements Runnable {
    public boolean running = false;
    private Thread clientThread;

    Frame frame;
    public Client() {
        super("localhost", 43594);

        frame = new ClientFrame(500, 500);
        start();
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if(running) return;
        running = true;

        clientThread = new Thread(this);
        clientThread.start();
    }
    public synchronized void stop() {
        if(!running) return;
        running = false;

        clientThread.interrupt();
        try {
            clientThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public void run() {
        try{
        setupStream();

        while(running) {
            System.out.println("running");
        }
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try{
            out.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();
            clientThread.join();
            }catch(IOException | InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Client();
    }
}
```

Stream.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Stream {

    Socket socket;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    String data;

    public Stream(String host, int port) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(host, port);
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void setupStream() throws IOException {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.flush();
        in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    }

}
```

My Server Thread:

```
package Server;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class User extends Thread {
    public static int users = 0;
    public int ID;
    public String username;
    boolean online = false;

    public static ArrayList<String> usernames = new ArrayList<String>();

    Socket socket;

    DataOutputStream out;
    DataInputStream in;
    String input;

    public User(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;

    }

    public String decode(String input) {
        String[] split = input.split(" ");

        if(input.startsWith("::")) {
            try {
                switch(split[0].substring(2, split[0].length()).toLowerCase()) {
                case "setname": 
                case "changename":
                case "newname":
                    if(usernames.contains(split[1].toLowerCase())) {
                        out.writeUTF("This name is already taken! Please choose a different one.");
                        out.flush();
                        return null;
                    }
                    if(username == null) {
                        username = split[1].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + split[1].substring(1, split[1].length());
                        Server.users.put(split[1].toLowerCase(), Server.user[ID]);
                        usernames.add(split[1].toLowerCase());
                    } else {
                        usernames.remove(username.toLowerCase());
                        username = split[1].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + split[1].substring(1, split[1].length());
                        usernames.add(split[1].toLowerCase());
                    }
                        return null;
                case "rank+":
                    return null;
                case "[sm]=":
                    return null;
                }
            }catch(IOException e) { }
        }
        return input;
    }

    String timeStamp;
    public void run() {
        try {

            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            while((input = in.readUTF()) != null) {
                input = decode(input);

                if(input != null) {
                    if(username != null) {
                        timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("[h:mm:ss] ").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                        Server.sendGlobalMessage(timeStamp + username +": "+input);
                    } else {
                        timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("[h:mm:ss] ").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                        Server.sendGlobalMessage(timeStamp + "Guest "+ID+": "+input);
                    }
                }
            }

        }catch(IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } finally { 
            try{
                out.close();
                in.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch(IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }

    }

}
```

I haven't touched the code of my Server Thread for a while, since it has always worked up until I made my new client.

Comment: You're silently ignoring the exceptions from `setupStream()`. Add at minimum `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch blocks.

Comment: @VinceEmigh you should worry about error handling, `Stream` constructor is always failing but since exception is suppressed nothing get noticed. Further `setupStream` throws NPE due to `null` `Socket` as there is nothing listening on it!

Comment: There are not all that many ways to not reach the line below `setupStreams()` (locking up, or an exception gets thrown). How do you know an exception does not get thrown if you never check that? You say you don't get any errors, but the code you have pasted is not capable of detecting that.

Comment: if you omit those stacktraces, how could people possibly know that you already know that there's no error? you diddn't talk about a server in the first place, and so it seems likely that you forgot about it and didn't realize it because of missing stacktraces...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your server does not create an `ObjectOutputStream`, so when the client constructs its `ObjectInputStream`, it blocks waiting for the object stream header, which never arrives.

Comment: It is exactly as I said. An ObjectInputStream needs an ObjectOutputStream at the other end, and *vice versa.* However the remarks about exception handling are not to be ignored. It isn't something you add to the program after you get it working. It is an essential part of getting it working in the first place.